# Cannot find symbol - antlr error

Tags: antlr

I get the "cannot find symbol error" on the insertchild function:

> calculatorParser.java:330: error: cannot find symbol
>   tempTree.InsertChild(((ValueContext)_localctx).e14.tree); ^ symbol:
>   method InsertChild(Tree) location: variable tempTree of type Tree

What am I doing wrong?

```
exp returns [Tree tree] : 
    LBRACKET 
    e1=value{$tree.insertChild($e1.tree);}
    RBRACKET
    | e2=value{$tree.insertChild($e2.tree);}
;

value returns [Tree tree]:
                            e3=exp DOLLAR e4=exp {
                                                    Tree tempTree= new Tree('$');
                                                    tempTree.InsertChild($e3.tree);
                                                    tempTree.InsertChild($e4.tree);
                                                    $tree=tempTree;
                                                }
```

This is the tree structure:

```
public Tree(String value){
    this.value = value;
    childList = new LinkedList<Tree>();
}
//Insert a subtree as a child
public void insertChild(Tree child){
    childList.addLast(child);
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the exact, complete, full, literal error text?

Comment: calculatorParser.java:330: error: cannot find symbol
                  tempTree.InsertChild(((ValueContext)_localctx).e14.tree);
                          ^
  symbol:   method InsertChild(Tree)
  location: variable tempTree of type Tree

Comment: Thank you.  Now can you paste your full compiler and linker commands?  Your build system may have a "verbose" option you can enable to display these.

Comment: java org.antlr.v4.Tool calculator.g
javac *.java

Comment: Isn't Java case sensitive?

Comment: oops that was my mistake, now it fixed but when im trying to create lisp tree style i gets another error, these are the commands and the error:
java org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig calculator init –tree
Warning: TestRig moved to org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig; calling automatically
Problems calling org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig.main(args)